the quadratic equation $x^2+(a+b) x+c=0$ has no real roots

If $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and the quadratic equation $x^2+(a+b) x+c=0$ has no real roots, then
(A) $c(a+b+c)>0$
(B) $c+c(a+b+c)>0$
(C) $c-c(a+b+c)>0$
(D) $c(a+b-c)>0$


By checking the discriminant, and it having no real roots, I got that $(a+b)^{2}<4c$ but that doesn't correspond to any of the options, how do I proceed?

Maybe it's wrong? Have you been looking for a possible counter-example?

$f(0)$ and $f(1)$ will be of the same sign. Option B matches

Just let $x = c$ and you can get $c^{2}+c(a+b)+c＞0$, which can be represented as option B.

Let $f(x) = x^2 + (a+b)x + c$. Assume that $a > 0$, then $f(x) > 0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb R$. Why? Because $f(x)$ does not intersect with the x axis! Hence, $f(1) > 0 \implies a+b+c+ 1 > 0$.
Now, assume $a < 0 \implies f(x) < 0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb R$. Hence, $f(1) < 0, \implies a + b + c + 1 < 0$.
Can you solve it now after combining it with the fact that $(a+b)^2 < 4c$?

Since $(a+b)^2<4c$ we have that $c>0$. So the four options are equivalent to

(A) $a+b+c>0$
(B) $1+a+b+c>0$
(C) $1 - (a+b+c)>0$
(D) $a+b-c>0$

(A) is false: Take $a=-2$, $b=0$ and $c=\frac{3}{2}$.
(C) and (D) are false: Take $a=b=0$ and $c=2$
Now we prove (B) has to happen:
Assume $1+a+b+c \le 0$. Then $1+c \le -(a+b)$. Since $1+c>0$, we have $(1+c)^2 \le (a+b)^2<4c$.
But then $1+2c+c^2<4c$, so $1-2c+c^2<0$, that is $(1-c)^2<0$, a contradiction. Then we have $1+a+b+c > 0$.

Let $f(x)=x^2+(a+b) x+c$.
We have $f'(x)=2x+a+b$.
But since $f(x)=0$ has no real roots, the entire graph of $f, C_f$ must lie either above or below the $x$-axis.
Since $f''(x)=2\gt0, f$ is concave thus $f(x)\gt0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
So $f(0)=c\gt0, f(1)=1+a+b+c\gt0\Rightarrow f(0)f(1)\gt0\Rightarrow c+c(a+b+c)>0$ which is option $(B)$.
